# Working out the average number of selections required to select each item of a list at least once when using random selection with replacement?

Tags: combinatorics, random

So, most combinatorics I've looked at while researching this consist of limiting the number of selections made from a set *X* and working out the probability of a particular combination of results.

In this instance I actually want to work out the average number of times I have to select an item from the set *X*, assuming replacement, before I have selected each item at least once. Now I can do this via an iterative process whereby I just run a selection loop until such time as I get each item at least once and then average several thousand iterations.

However, I am curious if it's possible to calculate this average in a more formulaic method.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)?